# R two table merge

Tags: r

I have two data.frame `df1` and `df2` .

```
df1=data.frame(id=c(1,2,2),var1=c(3,5,5),var3=c(2,3,4))
df2=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),var1=c('NONE','NONE','NONE','NONE'),var3=c(2,4,6,5))
```

now I want to merge to one data.frame. First, I should change the `df2$var1`. re encoding the `df2$var1` with `df1$var1` when `df2$id` match with `df1$id`. For example, `df1$id=1` `df1$var1=3` then `df2$id=1` and `df2$var1=3`, so the result should like this:

```
df1=data.frame(id=c(1,2,2),var1=c(3,5,5),var3=c(2,3,4)).
df2=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2),var1=c(3,3,5,5),var3=c(2,4,6,5))
```

secondly, I want to merge two data.frame and delete the same one.the result should like this:

```
df=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,2,2),var1=c(3,3,5,5,5,5),var2=c(2,4,3,4,6,5))
```

Sorry, it's my first to use stackoverflow. And most importantly,English isn't my native language.

---

Comment: `unique(rbind(df1, merge(df1[,-3], df2[,-2], by = 'id')))`

Comment: I think there's a small mistake in the example of the result that you gave. @HubertL and I both got a different result for the 3rd column of the 3rd and 4th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
union_all(df1, df2) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  arrange(id, var1)

  id var1 var3
1  1    3    2
2  1    3    4
3  2    5    3
4  2    5    4
5  2    5    6
6  2    5    5
```

First,I use dplyr::union,then I found that the order is disrupted.
So,finally I use union_all, then rank it

Comment: Need some explanation in the answer

Comment: That's a lot of code to acheive this result. Earlier answers were more concise and didn't introduce a new package dependency...

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select b.id, a.var1, b.var3 from df1 a left join df2 b on a.id = b.id")
```

> ```
>   id var1 var3
> 1  1    3    2
> 2  1    3    4
> 3  2    5    5
> 4  2    5    6
> 5  2    5    5
> 6  2    5    6
> ```

This is the same as the example you gave of your desired result, except for the 3rd column of the 3rd and 4th row. I believe that is due to a typo in your example, however if I am mistaken about this please let me know (and just explain why those values would be different and I will update my answer accordingly).

By the way, there are multiple ways to do this, but I find this one to be quick and easy.

Answer (score 0):

with `merge`:

```
df2$var1 <- df1[df2$id,'var1']; 
df2
  id var1 var3
1  1    3    2
2  1    3    4
3  2    5    6
4  2    5    5

df <- merge(df1, df2, by='id')[-2:-3]
df
  id var1.y var3.y
1  1      3      2
2  1      3      4
3  2      5      6
4  2      5      5
5  2      5      6
6  2      5      5
```